# Multiple Products in Backlog using Master Team Project in TFS

Tags: tfs, agile, azure-devops

I have been working to change my TFS structure to utilize only [one team project](http://nakedalm.com/working-within-a-single-team-project-with-team-foundation-server-2012/). I have set up my iterations and areas in the same fashion as the author of the article did, but still in my backlog I don't see any way of differentiating from each product. (I can see all projects, I'm not limited by "team").

Ex (Current Sprint 1 is a different project than Future Sprint 1):

[image]

Is there a way to do differentiate from each product in the backlog, other prep ending the name of the product to the Sprint name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to select a unique area or iteration for the Team you are working in.

So you could set it up like this:

**Team A**

- Backlog Iteration: `MyTeamProject\TeamA`
- Sprints:

  - `MyTeamProject\TeamA\Sprint 1`
  - `MyTeamProject\TeamA\Sprint 2`
  - etc.
- Area: `MyTeamProject`

This way Team A works in it's own set of iterations, but any item in any area of the Team Project appear on it's backlog - this is how my teams work.

Alternatively:

**Team A**

- Backlog Iteration: `MyTeamProject`
- Sprints:

  - `MyTeamProject\Sprint 1`
  - `MyTeamProject\Sprint 2`
  - etc.
- Area: `MyTeamProject\TeamAProduct` (e.g. Mobile App, Search, Database)

This way Team A works as part of the same set of iterations as everyone else, but only see's items on the backlog in their area of the product the are responsible for.

Finally, you could combine both together.

Comment: What I meant was, there is only one team and that team is responsible for all products. Not sure if this is any different than what I have, unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: If there is one team and they are responsible for all products then there is one cadence, and thus only one common sprint.

Comment: My organization also uses the "One Team Project" approach and I think we have a problem. We have lots of products, each product has a product owner. We only have 2 development teams and therefore two cadences. Each team has it's own backlog and board and we assign the appropriate areas. However, while the dev teams are sprinting, the Product Owners still need to maintain their own product backlogs, which might differ from those the Dev Teams are sprinting on. We could work around this by creating one team per product but I was hoping there was a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have some details to work out, I'm proceeding with using a sub iteration to designate the team's backlog but using area path to specify the product. ex:

**Iterations**
MyTeamProject\Team1

MyTeamProject\Team1\Iteration 1

MyTeamProject\Team1\Iteration 2

MyTeamProject\Team2

MyTeamProject\Team2\Iteration 1

MyTeamProject\Team2\Iteration 2

**Areas**

MyTeamProject\Product1

MyTeamProject\Product1\optional sub-area for product1

MyTeamProject\Product1\optional sub-area for product1

MyTeamProject\Product2

MyTeamProject\Product2\optional sub-area for product2

MyTeamProject\Product2\optional sub-area for product2

If you configure Team 1's areas to include ALL areas (under default area) but only iterations under Team 1, they will only see work items set to their iterations regardless of product (area path). There is a refinement step where new work items must be moved from the MyTeamProject\ iteration to the MyTeamProject\Team x iteration so it can be seen.

The result is Team x (scales to any number) sees their product backlog at MyTeamProject\Team x iteration and their current iteration backlog at MyTeamProject\Team x\Iteration x which can each be a mix of product areas via area path.

You'll end up with two teams in addition to the default team that is created with the team project. If you view backlogs at that level, you'll see everything regardless of iteration path or area path.

Advanced config is to create product teams for the product areas so product owners can view a version of the backlog regardless of iteration but only in their designated area path (for their product). Hope that helps.